# `queue` callback only executes once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, callback, jquery-callback

I have a jQuery function that loops. What I want to do is for the `$bird_wing_left` element to rotate 30 degrees and then rotate back to 0 degree (in an infinite loop).

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var rotate = 0;

    setInterval(function(){ 

        rotate = 30;

        $bird_wing_left.css({ transform: "rotate(" + rotate + "deg)" }).delay(1000).queue(function(){
            rotate = 0;
            $(this).css({ transform: "rotate(" + rotate + "deg)" });
        });

    }, 3000);
});
```

The first time it did rotate 30 degrees, then to 0 degrees, then to 30 degrees. However, afterwards, it seems to ignore the callback (which resets the degree value to 0), hence, it just keeps on being at 30 degrees on and on.

What could be the issue?

This is the jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/iamacatperson/86z26hdw/

Comment: are you getting any error in console?

Comment: any fiddle to work on? perhaps the problem is somewhere else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you `queue` a function, within the function you have to `dequeue` (or call "`next`", more below) to allow the queue to continue processing (as [shown in the examples](http://api.jquery.com/queue/#queue-queueName-callback)). Just add `$(this).dequeue()` within your queue callback:

```js
var $bird_wing_left = $("#wing");
$(document).ready(function() {

  var rotate = 0;

  setInterval(function() {

    rotate = rotate + 30;

    $bird_wing_left.css({
      transform: "rotate(" + rotate + "deg)"
    }).delay(1000).queue(function() {
      rotate = rotate - 30;
      $(this).css({
        transform: "rotate(" + rotate + "deg)"
      }).dequeue();       // <====================
    });

  }, 3000);
});
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div id="wing" style="width: 10em">Bird wing</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Alternately, since jQuery 1.4 the `queue` callback has been given an argument (traditionally called `next`) it can call to keep the queue going:

```js
var $bird_wing_left = $("#wing");
$(document).ready(function() {

  var rotate = 0;

  setInterval(function() {

    rotate = rotate + 30;

    $bird_wing_left.css({
      transform: "rotate(" + rotate + "deg)"
    }).delay(1000).queue(function(next) {  // <=====
      rotate = rotate - 30;
      $(this).css({
        transform: "rotate(" + rotate + "deg)"
      });
    
      next();                              // <=====
    });

  }, 3000);
});
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div id="wing" style="width: 10em">Bird wing</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Side note: You can use `+=` and `-=` if you like, e.g. `rotate += 30;` and `rotate -= 30;`

Comment: @A.Wolff: Looks that way from the docs, yeah, thanks. I added it as a second example.

Answer (score -1):

Quick fix could be to check rotate variable value before setting it.

```
if(rotate  == 0)
  rotate = rotate + 30;
else 
  rotate = 0;
```